# Get Resource file path C#

Tags: c#, resources, filepath, resource-file

How can I get the path of the resource file at runtime?
You access the resource by it's name: Properties.Resources.Lily.
I need to get the path of the file with the resource name "Lily": ../Resources/file_name.extension

Comment: Embedded resources are not physical files... Please clarify why (or when) you want to get file for the embedded resource.

Comment: This resource belongs project A. Project B have project A as a reference. In project B I need to set an image link. The image is a resource file in project A.